# how to Convert a cell of characters with spaces to decimal numbers?

Tags: matlab, ascii

I have a cell of chars and I wand to convert it to decimal

```
cellString = 

    'Tw'    'o '    'On'    'e '    'Ni'    'ne'    ' T'    'wo'
```

when I apply the function `hex2dec` it gives this error :

```
Input string found with characters other than 0-9, a-f, or A-F.
```

I know that this caused because of the spaces in `'o '` , `' e'` and `' T'`, but how can I solve it so I'll get in the end decimal numbers like that
`54 77 6F 20 4F 6E 65 20 4E 69 6E 65 20 54 77 6F` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your terminology is a little confused. The result that you have shown is *not* a decimal number. It is an array of hexadecimal numbers (notice the `A-F` characters throughout).

```
54 77 6F 20 4F 6E 65 20 4E 69 6E 65 20 54 77 6F
```

Second, calling `hex2dec` is of course going to fail because your input strings (even without the spaces) aren't hexadecimal (they have values other than `0-9` and `A-F`).

If I actually look at your input and expected output, what you *actually* want is the hexadecimal representation of your input string.

To do this, you first need to flatten your cell array into a single string. Then you can call `dec2hex`, and MATLAB will automatically convert each character in this string to it's ASCII representation (a decimal number) and then to it's hexadecimal equivalent.

```
cellString = {'Tw', 'o ', 'On', 'e ', 'Ni', 'ne', ' T', 'wo'};

% Combine cell array of strings into one long string
str = cat(2, cellString{:});

% Then convert to hexadecimal
H = dec2hex(str);

%   54
%   77
%   6F
%   20
%   4F
%   6E
%   65
%   20
%   4E
%   69
%   6E
%   65
%   20
%   54
%   77
%   6F
```

Comment: Thank you @Suever, this is exactly what I want. I was obviously confused about that.